# Difference between new String(char[]) and char[].toString

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

The output for following two code blocks in Java is different. I am trying to understand why.

```
private String sortChars(String s){
      char[] arr = s.toCharArray(); //creating new char[]
       Arrays.sort(arr); //sorting that array
        return new String(arr);  
    }
```

This one returns a string with sorted characters as expected.

```
private String sortChars(String s){
      char[] arr = s.toCharArray(); //creating new char[]
       Arrays.sort(arr); //sorting that array
        return arr.toString();
    }
```

Sorry. My bad!
Using to compare two strings.
The output to second string looks like this as suggested by many - 
[C@2e0ece65

Thanks!

Comment: In the second snippet, you're calling the `toString` method on the array herited from the Object class.

Comment: Is it not the other way round? i.e. `new String(arr)` returns the sorted string?

Comment: That is what the OP states: new String contains sorted value.

Comment: @ZouZou how would that matter? The array doesn't contain information about its order, it's implied to be linear

Comment: I'd be surprised if they really print a different character sequence.

Comment: Are you sure `arr.toString();` prints the string? I thought normal Java behaviour is to print the array identifier `[`, then the element type and then the hash code.

Comment: @jordan I don't get you, `arr.toString()` has the same behavior as the `toString` method from the `Object` class (`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`). So both snippet indeed return a different character sequence.

Comment: Was your original string the result of toString of the char[]?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Java, `toString` on an array prints `[`, then a character representing the array element type (`C` in this case) and then the identity hash code. So in your case, are you sure it is returning the original string and not something like `[C@f4e6d`?

Either way, you should use `new String(arr)`. This is the shortest, neatest, way of converting a `char[]` back to a `String`. You could also use [`Arrays.toString(arr)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28double%5B%5D%29)

*Related trivia*

The reason that your `arr.toString()` method returns something like `[Cf4e6d` is that [`Object.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) returns

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

For a `char` array, `getName()` returns the string `[C`. For your program you can see this with the code:

```
System.out.println(arr.getClass().getName());
```

The second part of the result, [`Object.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29), returns a number based on the object's memory address, not the array contents. This is because by default the definition of "equals" for an object is reference equality, i.e. two objects are the same only if they are the same referenced object in memory. You will therefore get different `arr.toString()` values for two arrays based on the same string:

```
String s = "fdsa";
char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
char[] arr2 = s.toCharArray();
System.out.println(arr.toString());
System.out.println(arr2.toString());
```

gives:

```
[C@4b7c8f7f
[C@5eb10190
```

Note that this is different for the `String` class where the equality rules are overridden to make it have value equality. However, you should always use [`string1.equals(string2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to test for string equality, and not `==` as the `==` method will still test for memory location.