# AES Encryption algorithm output string length (String) error?

Tags: java, encryption, aes, encryption-symmetric

```
 public static String encryptKey(String key,String text) throws CryptoException 
    {
        String key1=null;
        try {

            System.out.println("input parameters length  "+key.length()+ " " +text.length());
            System.out.println("input parameters value "+key+ " " +text);
            Key secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);

            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);             
            byte[] inputBytes=text.getBytes();
           //System.out.println(inputBytes.length);
            byte[] outputBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes);
           // key= WriteArray.bytesToString(outputBytes);  
           key1=outputBytes.toString();


            System.out.println("output parameters  "+key1.length()+" "+ text.length());
            System.out.println("output parameters value "+key1+ " " +text);
        }
```

The input and output string length are different. Why does this happen?

Is the problem of conversion string to byte array conversion? The output is shown below.

```
--------------------------------------
Level 1 Encryption Started
input parameters length  16 16
input parameters value 5iafq1b7d8i4hedu vg322qcfmnjbp3nj
output parameters  11 16
output parameters value [B@35851384 vg322qcfmnjbp3nj
--------------------------------------
Level 2 Encryption Started
input parameters length  16 11
input parameters value tvqfpjpul28ovo5c [B@35851384
output parameters  11 11
output parameters value [B@649d209a [B@35851384
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between new String(char\[\]) and char\[\].toString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23856703/difference-between-new-stringchar-and-char-tostring) Best I could find, but it's the same issue regardless whether you use `byte[]` or `char[]`

Answer (score 0):

Do not ever treat encrypted data as a String. It is binary data and almost certainly something bad is happening when you call `outputBytes.toString()`.

If you must treat the binary data as a string, you should apply a transformation that can deal with binary data and reliably produces a usable string. An example would be base64 encoding.

In your question, you seem to be expecting that the unencrypted text to be the same length as the encrypted bytes converted to a string. There is no reason why this would be true.

You should expect that if you encrypt and then decrypt the encrypted bytes that you get back your original message. However, the size of the encrypted data will almost certainly NOT be the same size.